# Oracle locking users when they use the same password

Tags: oracle, security, passwords

we have oracle set up to lock a user after 3 failed login attempts. however, when we change a password, we have some systems that will continue to use the old password for a few seconds. This is causing these accounts to get locked.

The purpose of locking an account is to prevent people from brute forcing a password.. but if systems just try the same password over and over, that's not really the point of locking the account. is there any way to allow the same password to be tried repetitively, but lock the account after 3 *different* passwords are tried?

Comment: Extreme good point, but I thing the answer is *NO* as IMO Oracle doesn't keep the passwords (or their hashes) used in a not successful connect attemt... So probablr only workaround would be a setting to 300 attemts or so, which is large enough for honest user and machines out of sync, but small enough for bad guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there's any simple syntax for this.

Looking [here](http://www.petefinnigan.com/weblog/archives/00001198.htm) you can probably develop a DDL trigger fired after an ALTER USER command that determines, from expiry_date on DBA_USERS, whether the password has just been changed. In that situation, it can change the profile to a less restrictive FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS. Then you'd have a batch job that picks up accounts with that profile after an hour or two, and sets it back to the standard profile.

Comment: I agree, but the devil is in the details. 'Less restrictive' should not mean 'no lockout', because that would give a certain amount of time for an attacker to try common passwords. It's surprisingly easy to find many user passwords based on wordlists... So 'less restrictive' should be the lowest number of failed attempts acceptable, and the timeframe the shortest acceptable (these obviously depend on how often out-of-sync systems try, and for how long until they are synced again).